# How can I change the default of the html short-cut "!" in vsc ? (So that I can add more html code)

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

With the exlclamation point!(In Visual Studio Code), you can easy and fast build the standart html-structure. I want to add some more Code to this standart html-structure to increase the Workflow.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: you can modify the emmet code file containing `!` but you need to do this Every time you update VSC. Simpler to just define an HTML snippet with the content you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to insert HTML boilerplate when you type `!`.  If so, the answer is VSCode "snippets," which are suggested when you type a certain character(s), and expand into whatever you define them to be.

Here's a link to the official documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Since you're a new user, I'll also mention that on Stack Overflow, it's expected that you provide a clear example of what you've tried so far, and what exactly didn't work.